# setState within setTimeout returns confusing results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, use-state

I'm trying to show a loader for 1.5s after submitting a form, then stop the loader and submit the form.
so I set a state variable `isSubmitting`:

```
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
```

`isSubmitting` is `false` by default, and upon submitting, I turn it to `true`, after that I set a timeout to set it back to `false`. but somehow, it does not get set back to `false` see commented code

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmitting(!isSubmitting);
    setTimeout(() => {
      createProfile(formData, history, edit);
      console.log(isSubmitting);// false - why?? its been set to true before the timeoute
      setIsSubmitting(!isSubmitting);
      console.log(isSubmitting);// false - if the previous log was false, this should of been true
    }, 1500);
  };
console.log(isSubmitting) // true - ??? it did not get set back to false
```

Comment: if I take off the `!` in the `setIsSubmitting` withting the `setTimeout` (`setIsSubmitting(isSubmitting)`) then it works

Comment: try ```setIsSubmitting(previous => !previous);```

Comment: Also if you can, make a demo on codesandbox and share link

Comment: Don't trust console.log, or stringify your content so it will only display a string. console.log get edited when your variable changes (sometimes). Also, there is a callback function in setState method() (whatever the name you use) that will allow you to wait for the value to be correctly set before to do something else.

Comment: It's because when you call `onSubmit` then first `setIsSubmitting` sets value to the `true`, then `setTimeout` is added to the event loop so then `console.log` from the last line is called with changed `true` value. Next after 1500ms comes result of timeout function -  but values are still old because `setIsSubmitting` is asynchronous and when timeout function was added to the event loop then values are not yet updated. You should create an `Promise` which resolves after 1500ms and using `async/await` or `.then` set proper value ;)

Comment: try to use the console.log in useEffect

Answer (score 1):

The state update using the updater provided by useState hook is asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect the updated changes.

i.e

```
console.log(isSubmitting); // false
setIsSubmitting(!isSubmitting);
console.log(isSubmitting); // false
```

Instead you should useEffect,

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmitting(!isSubmitting);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of isSubmitting
  if(isSubmitting) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      createProfile(formData, history, edit);
      setIsSubmitting(!isSubmitting);
    }, 1500);
  }
}, [isSubmitting]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how closures work in JS. The functions passed to setTimeout will get the `isSubmitting` variable from the initial render, since `isSubmitting` is not mutated.

You can get a function as an argument instead of prop to `setIsSubmitting`
That means that `isSubmitting` is gonna be updated value.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  setIsSubmitting(isSubmitting => !isSubmitting);
}, 1500);
```

Hope it will work

Comment: but how come in plain js, I dont have this problem? sounds like it has to do with useState?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe little overkill byt you can handle this by using `Promise`

```
const handleRequest = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     createProfile(formData, history, edit)
       .then(response => resolve(response))
       .catch(error => reject(error));
  }, 1500);
}

const onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setIsSubmitting(true);

  handleRequest().finally(() => setIsSubmitting(false);
};
```

And maybe second overkill: I'm not sure why you need to submit data after 1.5s, not immediately but you can have both 1.5s loader and request sended just after submit by creating some dummy `Promise` and using `Promise.all` like this:

```
const dummyPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1500);
}

const onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setIsSubmitting(true);

  Promise.all([
    dummmyPromise(),
    createProfile(formData, history, edit)
  ])
   .then(response => ...handle successfull response)
   .catch(error => ...handle request error)
   .finally(() => setIsSubmitting(false));
};
```

The thing is you don't know how long your request will last so by setup like this you are prepared for different situations: sumbmit request is sent immidately and `Promise.all` will resolve after all promises resolves so if your request resolves very fast you will still have 1.5s loader, on the other hand if request will last longer than 1.5s you will still have active loader indicating that request is not finished yet. Like I said overkill in your situation but I hope my comment will contain some nice inspirations how to improve handling async requests ;)

Comment: *"if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"* Promises ain't the solution to every Problem. You've casually "solved" OPs issue somewhere along the way by explicitely setting `setIsSubmitting(true)` and `setIsSubmitting(false)`, instead of trying to flip a *constant* `setIsSubmitting(!isSubmitting)` back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

> `isSubmitting` is `false` by default, and upon submitting, I turn it to `true`, after that I set a timeout to set it back to `false`. but somehow, it does not get set back to `false` see commented code

That **is** how closures work

> but how come in plain js, I dont have this problem? sounds like it has to do with useState?

Yes, in plain JS you have the same problem. I'll show you:

```js
let storedValue = false;

function setStoredValue(newValue) {
  storedValue = newValue
}

// useState() is basically this; more or less.
// The place where `storedValue` and `setStoredValue` are kept is differrent, 
// but that's not relevant to the issue at hand.
function gimmeTheValueAndASetter() {
  return [
    storedValue,
    setStoredValue
  ]
}

function Element(label) {
  // you create a local **constant** copy of the state at this moment
  const [localValue, setStoredValue] = gimmeTheValueAndASetter();

  // and all your logs here are based off of this local **constant**!
  console.log(label, "#1 local:", localValue, " stored:", storedValue);

  setStoredValue(!localValue);

  console.log(label, "#2 local:", localValue, " stored:", storedValue);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(label, "#3 local:", localValue, " stored:", storedValue);

    setStoredValue(!localValue);

    console.log(label, "#4 local:", localValue, " stored:", storedValue);
  }, 100);
}

// render Element
Element("first render");
console.log("after first render:", storedValue);
Element("second render");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Back to your code. Instead of flipping the state, better set the explicit value. This is also simpler to reason about:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // we don't want to submit while another submit is still in progress
  // right?
  if(isSubmitting) return; 

  setIsSubmitting(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    createProfile(formData, history, edit);
    setIsSubmitting(false);
  }, 1500);
};
```

Ain't this simpler to reason about than what you had before? `isSubmitting` was `false` then I've flipped it to `true`, so now I have to flip it again to get back to `false`, ...